# Raspberry Power Supply via GPIO. No HDMI or Ethernet

Tags: gpio, pi-4, power, supply

for my current project I need to supply the Pi via the GPIO pins with power. I know that I'm bypassing some security features, but my circuit has new ones implemented.

The problem is, that I'm hocking Pin 2 to 5V + and Pin 6 to GND. The Pi turns on and uses 800 mA. But I don't get an HDMI signal, and the Ethernet port is also not working.
I already tried adding "hdmi_force_hotplug=1" to the config.txt.
Is it a coding "problem" and how can I solve it?

HDMI/Ethernet work when I power the Pi normally, via USB, that's why I'm confused.

I use a Raspberry 4B 8GB RAM

I had a look on HATs which supply the Pi via GPIO. The only extra think they have, is a Load Switch. Could this be the solution?
HAT: https://www.tinkerforge.com/de/shop/hat-brick.html
Load Switch: TPS22975

Comment: Yes it does. Thats why i'm confused.

Comment: I added this info to the question. I know it's obvious to you, but it's absolutely not for other people, and just asks for irrelevant answers such as "check your cables" etc.

Comment: Now, 800 mA can be too much or too little, depending on you Pi model. It sounds like a reasonable current for a Pi 4 with no CPU load. Is that so?

Comment: But as far as I understand it, the Pi takes that Current that he needs.

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly why it's a useful information. A broken Pi often takes very little current, and excessive current can indicate problems as well. The nominal current depends on the model though, so you should say which one you have.

Comment: I use a Raspberry 4B 8GB RAM (Added the Info to the Post)

Comment: Start by measuring the voltage you deliver to the Pi, using separate pins (e.g. 4 and 14). It should be above 5V ideally.

Comment: "I know that I'm bypassing some security features" you can't because the Pi4 doesn't have any. The 5V pins are directly connected to the VBUS input.

Answer (score 2):

You need to supply more power.

Your power supply to the GPIO is clearly inadequate.

It could be the wires used or the power supply or poor connections.  We can't guess which.